# Problem in formula when referencing cells in another worksheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, axlsx

I am trying to access the values of specific cells of another worksheet

But I have a problem in my formula when I add it to a cell

this is my formula:

```
=ÍNDICE(Categorias!A2:A6, COINCIDIR(G2, Categorias!B2:B6, 0))
```

this is my complete code

```
$ACTIVITIES.each do |key, value|
    wb.add_worksheet(name: key) do |sheet|
        sheet.add_row $TITLE, style: $STYLE_HEADER
        data = value.sort_by { |hour| hour[:begin_date] }
        data.each do |activity|
            sheet.add_row [
                activity[:id],
                activity[:name],
                activity[:description],
                activity[:begin_date],
                activity[:end_date],
                "=ÍNDICE(Categorias!A2:A6, COINCIDIR(G2, Categorias!B2:B6, 0))"
            ], :widths => [:ignore, 50, 50, :auto, :auto]


            sheet.col_style(3, date_time, row_offset: 1)
            sheet.col_style(4, date_time, row_offset: 1)
        end

    end
end
```

but in excel he shows me this:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOC8A.png)

**How can I solve this ?, help please**

Answer (score 0):

probably you solved your issue by now.

This morning it took me almost 2 hours to figure it out.

for me what worked was `'sheet_name'!coordinates`

so for example, if I wanted to refer the cell to another sheet I would do

```
='sheet_1'!F3
```

In my case needed `SUMIFS` so the code I used was

```
=SUMIFS('sheet_1'!F:F, 'sheet_1'!A:A, C2)
```

Hope it would be helpful for someone